# Home security alarm system in the uk

Tags: security, alarm

Can anyone suggest the best home security alarm? Most famous one is ADT in the uk which is monitored alarm system. Is it non-monitored alarm system much secure than monitored one?
Can some one please suggest me for the best alarm system for the home security.

My home is like end terraced which has front door, back door and back garden. I am really interested to put security alarm system in the outer part of the home like doors and windows.
Thank you

Comment: Please see [here](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/607/can-we-discourage-shop-for-me-type-questions) for more information about our policy for this type of question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best alarm system you can have is three large well-trained guard dogs. I can say that, since I've done security electronics in some of the more secure places in this world, and for a while I had every-day conversations with professional burglars.

Comment: You mean guard dog as a real dog. Sorry we don't have time to look after a 3 dogs. Busy at work during the weekdays and weekends only free.

Comment: Yep, real dogs. You could put up two fencelines and let the dogs return to the wild between them...

Comment: The best alarm system isn't one that tells ANYBODY that a break-in has just happened. The best alarm system is one that turns away break-ins BEFORE they happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer but still not fully convinced.

Comment: Not so useful when you have to go away for a few days and can't find anybody to look after them...